# Execute a line based on .ext with .bat Batch File?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have either 01.png, 01.jpg or 01.webp and the file.bat in the same folder.

based on these .ext I want to execute a command in .bat

```
if 01.png exist then
    do something
or if 01.jpg exist then
    do something
or if 01.webp exist then
    do something
```

Is this possible with BATCH or even .cmd?

Comment: The comment from @DrMoishePippik is on the money but if you still need help, come back and someone can help you with the if - else logic.. of course batch can do this.

Comment: Yes, also @It Wasn't Me answer!

Comment: 1 minute after @SeñorCMasMas put this comment, I add the answer.. d:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try if() else if() else if ()...

```ps1
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"

if exist 01.png (
         command 
       ) else if exist 01.jpg (
         command
       ) else if exist 01.webp (
         command
       )
```

---

If you need, you can add an else to handle the nonexistence of your files...

```ps1
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"

if exist 01.png (
         command
       ) else if exist 01.jpg (
         command
       ) else if exist 01.webp (
         command
       ) else echo file not exist
```

- Some further reading: **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

Comment: Much obliged, simple and does the trick.